# error in connection string in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset



strConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Hospital_ABC;Data Source=ITEM-47791\SQLEXPRESS;Persyst Security Info=False;Command Properties='Command Time Out=45'"





Set connexion = New ADODB.Connection

connexion.ConnectionString = strConnectionString

connexion.ConnectionTimeout = 30

connexion.Open strConnectionString

rs.Open "insert into student_info(name,rollNo,age, class,address,assigned_teacher)values('name',rollno,age,'cls','add','assteac')", connexion
```

i am using this code to insert value inn my table ,,,but i got error as--run time error( multiple step OLEDB operation generated error, check each OLEDB status value, if available)
please check it what wrong in thos code  .....

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269495

It says:

> The following are two possible causes
>   of this error:
>
> 1. In the registry, under the key for an OLE DB provider's CLSID, there may
>      be an entry named OLEDB_SERVICES. If
>      the OLE DB provider that is used to
>      make the ADO connection does not have
>      the OLEDB_SERVICES entry, and ADO
>      tries to set up a property that is not
>      supported by the provider, the error
>      occurs. For more information about
>      this registry entry, see the
>      "Resolution" section.
> 2. If OLEDB_SERVICES entry exists but there is a problem in the ADO
>      connection string, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use this in connection string
Persyst Security Info=False;Command Properties='Command Time Out=45'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
rs.Open "insert into student_info(name,rollNo,age,class,address,assigned_teacher) values('n',1,1,'c','a','a')", connexion
```

For me, the error usually happens when a data is too long for the field. You can further troubleshoot this by updating one field at a time to find the one that is broken (Update name, then update name and number, then name and number and age, etc).